# How to get the destinations of two instances of VLC

Tags: command-line, d-bus, vlc

If you have only one instance of VLC running, you can talk to VLC with dbus-send using org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc as destination:

```
$ dbus-send --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc  ...
```

If you have two instances of VLC running, they have different destinations xxxx and yyyy. If you want to talk to one of them, you must use xxxx or yyyy as destination:

```
$ dbus-send --dest=:xxxx   ...
```

The destination of the first instance I can find in this way:

```
$ dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus  /org/freedesktop/DBusorg.freedesktop.DBus.ListQueuedOwners  string:org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc

method return time=1702494718.199915 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.1256 serial=3 reply_serial=2
   array [
      string ":1.1251"
   ]
```

Then I see that the destination is 1.1251

But how can I get the destination of the second instance?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by destinations. Did you try looking at the output of `ps auexww | grep -i '[V]LC'` ? Maybe that will give you more clues.

Comment: @shelter   Does not help me. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i always use busctl to get the complete dbus infos.
There is a system bus (busctl --system) and a session bus (busctl --user) or complete list (busctl -l) 
enter:

`busctl --user | grep "vlc"`

then you get something like this

```
:1.641                                              91266 vlc             xxxxx :1.641        session-c2.scope  c2      -
:1.642                                              91266 vlc             xxxxx :1.642        session-c2.scope  c2      -
:1.643                                              91266 vlc             xxxxx :1.643        session-c2.scope  c2      -
:1.644                                              91266 vlc             xxxxx :1.644        session-c2.scope  c2      -
:1.654                                              91361 vlc             xxxxx :1.654        session-c2.scope  c2      -
:1.655                                              91361 vlc             xxxxx :1.655        session-c2.scope  c2      -
:1.656                                              91361 vlc             xxxxx :1.656        session-c2.scope  c2      -
:1.657                                              91361 vlc             xxxxx :1.657        session-c2.scope  c2      -
org.kde.StatusNotifierItem-91266-2                  91266 vlc             xxxxx :1.644        session-c2.scope  c2      -
org.kde.StatusNotifierItem-91361-2                  91361 vlc             xxxxx :1.657        session-c2.scope  c2      -
org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc                          91266 vlc             xxxxx :1.641        session-c2.scope  c2      -
org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc.instance91361            91361 vlc             xxxxx :1.654        session-c2.scope  c2
```

The org files are the active services. 
you see there is a second service called org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc.instance91361 
the first vlc instance is on PID 91266, the second vlc instance is on PID 91361

here in my example call:

`dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus  /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ListQueuedOwners  string:org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc.instance91361`

will give you your information about the second instance

----------- By the way

you can examine the dbus service for the object tree 
`busctl --user tree org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc.instance91361`

you get:

```
└─/org
  └─/org/mpris
    └─/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2
```

then you also can introspect the objects
`busctl --user introspect org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc.instance91361 /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2`

output:

```
NAME                                TYPE      SIGNATURE RESULT/VALUE                             FLAGS
org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable interface -         -                                        -
.Introspect                         method    -         s                                        -
org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties     interface -         -                                        -
.Get                                method    ss        v                                        -
.GetAll                             method    s         a{sv}                                    -
.Set                                method    ssv       -                                        -
.PropertiesChanged                  signal    sa{sv}as  -                                        -
org.mpris.MediaPlayer2              interface -         -                                        -
.Quit                               method    -         -                                        -
.Raise                              method    -         -                                        -
.CanQuit                            property  b         true                                     emits-change
.CanRaise                           property  b         false                                    emits-change
.CanSetFullscreen                   property  b         false                                    emits-change
.DesktopEntry                       property  s         "vlc"                                    emits-change
.Fullscreen                         property  b         false                                    emits-change writable
.HasTrackList                       property  b         false                                    emits-change
.Identity                           property  s         "VLC media player"                       emits-change
.SupportedMimeTypes                 property  as        29 "audio/mpeg" "audio/x-mpeg" "video/m… emits-change
.SupportedUriSchemes                property  as        21 "file" "http" "https" "rtsp" "realrt… emits-change
org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player       interface -         -                                        -
.Next                               method    -         -                                        -
.OpenUri                            method    s         -                                        -
.Pause                              method    -         -                                        -
.Play                               method    -         -                                        -
.PlayPause                          method    -         -                                        -
.Previous                           method    -         -                                        -
.Seek                               method    x         -                                        -
.SetPosition                        method    ox        -                                        -
.Stop                               method    -         -                                        -
.CanControl                         property  b         true                                     emits-change
.CanPause                           property  b         false                                    emits-change
.CanPlay                            property  b         false                                    emits-change
.CanSeek                            property  b         false                                    emits-change
.LoopStatus                         property  s         "None"                                   emits-change writable
.MaximumRate                        property  d         32                                       emits-change writable
.Metadata                           property  a{sv}     0                                        emits-change
.MinimumRate                        property  d         0.032                                    emits-change writable
.PlaybackStatus                     property  s         "Stopped"                                emits-change
.Position                           property  i         0                                        emits-change
.Rate                               property  d         1                                        emits-change writable
.Shuffle                            property  d         false                                    emits-change writable
.Volume                             property  d         0                                        emits-change writable
org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.TrackList    interface -         -                                        -
.AddTrack                           method    sob       -                                        -
.GetTracksMetadata                  method    ao        aa{sv}                                   -
.GoTo                               method    o         -                                        -
.RemoveTrack                        method    o         -                                        -
.CanEditTracks                      property  b         true                                     emits-change
.Tracks                             property  ao        0                                        emits-change
.TrackAdded                         signal    a{sv}o    -                                        -
.TrackListReplaced                  signal    aoo       -                                        -
.TrackMetadataChanged               signal    oa{sv}    -                                        -
.TrackRemoved                       signal    o         -                                        -
```

you see all defined interfaces and methods.

for example, lets take the "OpenUri" method from the interface: org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player

`busctl --user call org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player OpenUri s "your url"` 
-- will open the video in the first instance

`busctl --user call org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc.instance91361 /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player OpenUri s "your url"` 
-- will open a video in the second instance

call Syntax:
============
call SERVICE OBJECT INTERFACE METHOD [SIGNATURE [ARGUMENT...]]
for further information - see busctl - help

have a nice day!

Comment: Very helpful! I didn't know about busctl. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @EddySorngard : You can also up-vote this answer to give further reputation points to Schmaehgrunza.

Comment: @EddySorngard i forgot to tell you, the number you search for, you also get with busctl --user status org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc, search for UniqueName for example =:1.641, every service is also reachable over a unique number, instead of the name org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc you can also use :1.641, for example - busctl --user tree :1.641,